# paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: vs updatedTransactions:

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am restoring completed transactions (recurring) with

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

and in

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

I got a list of history transactions restored, made by the app, but the method:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

is not even called once, so I wonder which one should I use? I did some research and found that `updatedTransactions:` method should be used with checking transaction state, but if I got a list of transactions restored, it is just meaningless to treat them all as transactions. Which one should I use? Does `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` only gives me the latest one (ie sandbox subscription expires in several minutes and I got a full list of history transactions made when testing, in `updatedTransactions`).

Comment: I think `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is called if the user initiates a restore but there are no purchases on ASC to restore. You may need to hook into this in case it's necessary to stop a loading spinner, provide a message, etc. Otherwise it is not important.

Comment: I can confirm from testing that `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is called regardless if there are transactions to restore or there are no transactions to restore, whereas `updatedTransactions` is called *only* if there are transactions to restore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an excellent WWDC Video about using StoreKit, it is WWDC2012 Session 302.

To isolate each purchase, your `updatedTransactions` method could look something like this:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

            switch(transaction.transactionState) {
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                    // Unlock content
                    //... Don't forget to call `finishTransaction`!
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                    // Maybe show a progress bar?
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                    // Handle error
                    // You must call finishTransaction here too!
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                    // This is the one you want ;)
                    // ...Re-unlock content...
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    break;
             }
         }
}
```

Once you've determined that the purchase is being restored, you can make content available as you see fit - preferably by calling a separate method from within that switch statement and passing the transaction as a parameter. The implementation is up to you of course.

Comment: Yes, but what I got is more than 1 transactions restored for the same product ID, then do I use the transaction with most recent transactionDate?

Comment: Hmm that shouldn't be happening... That possibly means, previously, the transaction wasn't completed with `finishTransaction:`. I'd reset your App (clean build and delete data from the iOS Simulator) to get rid of the queued transactions. Before you do that though, where are you setting up your `TransactionObserver`?

Comment: Maybe missing break in the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing case?

Answer (score 3):

1. Call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]` in `(void)viewDidLoad` or equivalent if applicable.
2. Then call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`.
3. `(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` will be called accordingly through (2).

If you don't call the method in (1), the application will never reach (3) to restore transactions in the first place.

Comment: Yes I did do 1. the problem is the method in 3. gives me a list of all subscription the sandbox account has made. I only need the one which is successfully restored.

Comment: @hzxu i have same problem, Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished never getting called.  I fixed by going to iTunes & Aoo Stores in Settings and logged out of the sandbox test account and tried it again.  Worked as expected the next time after being prompted to login again on a restore.

Comment: I am pretty sure I would never have tried this as a fix, but it was exactly my issue.  Thank you very much! I certainly hope this is a "dev environment" issue... seems like a lot of apps would break if this happened in prod.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Docs:

> paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: This method is called
>   after all restorable transactions have been processed by the payment
>   queue. Your application is not required to do anything in this method.